# wifi won't stay conneted after upgrade

Tags: 14.04

02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter (rev 01)  won't stay connected

Toshiba Satellite

Please help I have to reboot to get connected again it's a real pain!